# How to update a KDB date partition in the same segment

Tags: kdb

I have the below tables in the standard splayed format where they are partitioned by date with each column as separate file under the table name.
../archive/2010.01.03/TradingHistory_EQU_ASI_DISCRETIONARY/col1, col2, col3,....
../archive/2010.01.03/TradingHistory_EQU_ASI_MULTIQUANT/col1, col2, col3,....
../archive/2010.01.03/TradingHistory_EXCEPTION_MULTIQUANT/col1, col2, col3,....

What is the correct method to rename/update the date partition to the next day (2010.01.04)
assuming the same tables defined here in 2010.01.03 exist and are populated for 2010.01.04.
Essentially, I wanted to merge the data for these tables for 2010.01.03 and 2010.01.04 whilst leaving the merged data in the 2010.01.04 date partition?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge (insert or upsert) the 2010.01.03 data to the 2010.01.04 table using the following command:

```
  .Q.par[`:archive;2010.01.04;`TradingHistory_EQU_ASI_DISCRETIONARY] upsert get 
  .Q.par[`:archive;2010.01.03;`TradingHistory_EQU_ASI_DISCRETIONARY]
```

where the first argument of .Q.par is the path of the database, the second is the date partition and the third is the table name.